# Why wolfram alpha assumed $ x>0$ as a domain of definition for $x^x $?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, wolfram-alpha

I'm confused why [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex) defined the function $x^x $ for $x>0$ , only what i think that it were defined it as :$e^{x\log x}$ , but the domain of definition depend to the function form .then : Why wolfram alpha  assumed  $ x>0$  as a domain of definition for  $x^x $ ?

**Note:** for example $x$ and $e^{\log x}$ are equivalent form but they don't have the same domain of definitin .

**Edit:** I have edited the question just to give an example without changing the meaning of the question

Comment: The (real) domain of the logarithm is $x>0.$

Comment: I'm interested in your definition of, say $(-\sqrt{2})^{-\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{x\log  x}$$

is defined where the exponent $x\log x$ is defined. Even if $x$ is defined on the whole real line, the function $\log x$ is defined only on the open set $]0,\infty[$. Hence the natural domain is such interval, *i.e.* $x>0$.

**EDIT** (The natural domain of $x^x$ without using the form $e^{x\log x}$).

The function $b^x$ is defined if and only if $b>0$. Now you may consider the function $b(x)^x$, where $b$ depends on $x$, and also in this case $b(x)$ must be a positive function (this include that can be constant and positive). In particular $b(x)$ may be the identity function, that is $b(x)=x$. Hence $x=b(x)>0$. Hence the natural domain for $x^x$ is $]0,\infty[$.

Comment: but i seek for this form : x^x not e^xlogx , For example : x is defined over R but e^logx is defined only for x >0 , and here x^x is defined also for x as negative integers

Comment: These forms are equivalent

Comment: and also x and e^logx are equivalent

Comment: $x(\in \mathbb{R})$ and $e^{\log x}$ are equivalent in the domain of the real $\log$ function, which is $(0,\infty)$. However, $x^x$ has *no meaning other than* $e^{x\log x}$. Otherwise, you may provide an alternative definition for $x^a$ and $b^x$ which allows $x^x$ to be defined for all real numbers, but this definition may not be consistent with the usual one.

Comment: I edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

irrational powers of negative real numbers are not defined, moreover, the fractional powers of negative numbers are not single valued. I think I can write a much clearer answer, but for now, here is a simple demonstration of the problem:

Let us try to evaluate $\left(-\frac m n\right)^{-\frac mn}$
$$\left(-\frac m n\right)^{-\frac mn}=\sqrt[n]{\left(-\frac n m\right)^m}.$$
Now, for an odd $m$, if $n$ is even, the answer is complex, if it is odd, there is a negative real answer.

Now imagine you have a sequence of rational numbers $\{x_n\}$ converging to some negative irrational number $x$ in a way that the parity of the denominator changes through out the sequence. Obviously $x_n^{x_n}$ does not converge, as it oscillates between real and complex numbers. So, how can we define $x^x$?

It doesn't even quit make sense to define this for all the rational numbers, because how would you determine if $(-0.6)^{-0.6}$ is positive or negative. Do we simplify $6/10$ to $3/5$ first which gives us a negative number, or do we not, which gives a positive number?

Comment: but look this :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex+,+x%3D-5

Comment: Right, you can define $k^k \in \mathbb{Q}$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. The issue comes from all the numbers in between. Note that Im(x^x) = 0 for all integers, which you can see for the first 10 negative integers clearly here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Im(x%5Ex)+%3D+0